# Associate activity with database ID

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-activity

I have a main ListView that is based on an adapter from my database. Each database id is "assigned" to an Activity via the ListView. And in my AndroidManifest, each activity has an intent filter with a custom action. Now with this, I have had to create this class:

```
public final class ActivityLauncher {
    private ActivityLauncher() { }

    public static void launch(Context c, int id) {
        switch(id) {
         case 1:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(SomeActivity.ACTION_SOMEACTIVITY);
            c.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 2:
            ...
            break;
        ...
        }
    }

    private static void st(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(action);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

So I have to manually create a new case for the switch statement. This would get troublesome if I have to rearrange or delete an id. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure on your reasoning but here's a punt. Make an object that encapsulates the behaviour you want.

```
public class User {
    private static final User[] users = new User[2];
    static {
         user[0] = new User(0, "Action_0");
         user[1] = new User(1, "Action_1");
    }

    private final int id;
    private final String action;

    public User(int id, String action){
          this.id = id;
          this.action = action;
    }

    public int getId(){
           return this.id;
    }

    public Intent getIntent(){
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setAction(this.action);
           return intent;
    }

    public static User getUser(int id){
        for(int i=0; i < users.length; i++){
             User user = user[i];
             if(id == user.getId()){
                 return user;
             }
        }
        throw new Resources.NotFoundException("User not found with id: "+id);
    }

}
```

So then in your activity you can have:

```
 public void launch(Context c, int id) {
       Intent intent = User.getUser(id).getIntent();
       c.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

or something along those lines, you could extend this further and pass round '`User`' objects instead of your raw id. You could also pass the context into the `getIntent` method and change it to a '`start`' method. `User` is probably a bad name for this class I'm just unsure on your domain.